# The badness value is always 10000

Tags: badness

I use WinEdt8.1 to create my TeX files and I prefer PDFTeX instead of TeX or LaTeX. I noticed that when I create an underfull box (horizontal or vertical) the badness value is always 10000. For example in that code

```
\hbox to250pt{\hskip0pt minus50pt\vrule height1pt width249pt}
```

the badness value should be 0.0008 [97]:

```
L= 249 . . . l=250 => D=-1 < 0
r=-(D/Y)=1/50 => badness = min(100*r^3,10000)=0.0008
```

But it is always 10000. I am sure you can say something...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The glue inside the box has no stretchability. So the glue stretch ratio is infinite.

Comment: Thank you, egreg. I am deep and I didn't noticed that I am writing minus.

Comment: Just so you know, `pdftex` is just an engine; it is separate from the idea of formats such as 'plain TeX' and 'LaTeX'. Other engines are `tex`, `xetex`, and `luatex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The glue inside the box has no stretchability, but the material doesn't cover the stated width. The glue stretch ratio *r* is thus infinite and the shown badness is 10000.

If you add stretchability, then the badness decreases:

```
\count255=0
\loop
  \hbox to20pt{\hskip0pt plus \count255 pt\vrule height1pt width1pt}
  \ifnum\count255<20
  \advance\count255 by 1
\repeat

\bye
```

Here's the terminal output:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 6
 |

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 6
 |

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 6
 |

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 6
 |

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 6
 |

Underfull \hbox (badness 5475) detected at line 6
 |

Underfull \hbox (badness 3168) detected at line 6
 |

Underfull \hbox (badness 1997) detected at line 6
 |

Underfull \hbox (badness 1337) detected at line 6
 |
```

The first nine boxes are considered underfull.